# tomcat + spring mvc: trimSpaces

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am trying to use Tomcat's trimSpaces attribute, but the problem is that with Spring it doesn't work. I wanted to use some Spring method insted and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691667/can-spring-mvc-trim-all-strings-obtained-from-forms), but my application fails with exception (please see the last comments of best answer).
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trimSpaces attribute of Tomcat does not trim spaces from form fields. It is used to remove white spaces around JSP tags. If this is your JSP file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<%@page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<head>
```

it will render client-side as

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">



<head>
```

With the Tomcat trimSpaces=true it will look like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
```

The whitespaces around the JSP tags are trimmed. This does not sound like the thing yuo want.

Comment: Actually, this is what I need. But the problem that if I add such attribute to web.xml (of tomcat, not of application) - nothing happens. May be it is because of Spring MVC?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in application's `web.xml`.

```
  <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
```

[Trim Spaces in your JSP's](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/trim_spaces_in_your_jsp1)